# Recurrence relation of ordinary power series generating function

Tags: combinatorics

The sequence $\{b_n\}^\infty_{n=0}$ is defined by $b_0 = 3, b_1 = 7$ and the recurrence relation
$$b_{n+2} = 2b_{n+1} - b_n +1$$

for $n \ge 0$. Let $g(x)$ be the ordinary power series generating function of $\{b_n\}^\infty_{n=0}$.

Show that $$g(x) = \frac{3 - 2x}{(1-x)^3}.$$

I have worked out that $\{b_{n+1}\}^\infty_{n=0} = \frac{g(x) - 3}{x}$ and $\{b_{n+2}\}^\infty_{n=0} = \frac{g(x) - 3 - 7x}{x^2}$ and so $$\frac{g(x) - 3 - 7x}{x^2} = 2(\frac{g(x) - 3}{x}) - g(x) +1.$$

But when I rearrange this I get $g(x) = \frac{x^2 + x + 3}{(1-x)^2}$ which isn't the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach it as follows. First, shift the indices in the recurrence down by $2$ to get $b_n=2b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}+1$. Then adjust it so that it’s valid for $n\ge 0$ on the assumption that $b_n=0$ for all $n<0$:

$$b_n=2b_{n-1}-b_{n-2}+1+2[n=0]\;,$$

where $[n=0]$ is an [Iverson bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket). Now multiply through by $x^n$ and sum over $n\ge 0$, so that the lefthand side is simply $g(x)$, and simplify:

$$\begin{align*}
g(x)&=2\sum_{n\ge 0}b_{n-1}x^n-\sum_{n\ge 0}b_{n-2}x^n+\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n+2\\
&=2\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^{n+1}-\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^{n+2}+\frac1{1-x}+2\\
&=2xg(x)-x^2g(x)+\frac{3-2x}{1-x}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Solve for $g(x)$:

$$\left(1-2x+x^2\right)g(x)=\frac{3-2x}{1-x}\;,$$

so

$$g(x)=\frac{3-2x}{(1-x)(1-2x+x^2)}=\frac{3-2x}{(1-x)^3}\;.$$

---

By the way, your $\{b_{n+1}\}^\infty_{n=0} = \frac{g(x) - 3}{x}$ doesn’t actually make sense: the lefthand side is a sequence, and the righthand side is a power series. What you mean, I think, is that

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}b_{n+1}x^n=\frac{g(x)-3}x\;,$$

which is correct. Similarly,

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}b_{n+2}x^n=\frac{g(x)-3-7x}{x^2}\;.$$